# Rotate a Vector by Quaternions

Tags: mathematics, vector, quaternion, rotate

I'm trying how to work out how to Rotate a Vertex using Quaternions, using a scientific calculator, or on paper. Exam preparation.

My lecturer has given us this;
Quaternion = (-0.5, 0, -0.7071067, 0.5)
Vertex = (23, 10, 18)

The way it's been explained to us is like this;

- We have a vertex called **p**
- We have a quaternion called **q**
- We store **p** within a quaternions vector component, we'll call this **K**
- K = (0, p)
- Finally we do the normal quaternion multiplication
- **p'** = qKq-1

I'm just trying to work out how I break this down so it's easier to understand so I am able to find out the result. I know how to do quaternion multiplication, but it seems confusing as I only have one w component in the quaternion, and only the x, y,z in the vector.

Comment: What happens when you try to do , say, the left multiplication, `(q.w, q.x, q.y, q.z) * (0, p.x, p.y, p.z)`, using your rules for the quaternion basis units `i*i = -1`, `i*j = k`... etc?

Comment: Maybe you'd find it easier to find answers on [Mathematics StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) ?